# Placing font awesome inside a text field of a form

Tags: php, html

I'm fairly new at this and I have been trying very hard to place a font awesome icon inside one of my text fields in a booking form. While I have seen all relevant questions and answers, either they are too specific, or I do not know how to implement them to my specific issue. 
So this is the code I have for the specific field:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input 
      type="text"  
      name="country"  
      id="country"  
      placeholder="<?php _e( 'country', 'ci_theme' ); ?>"  
      value="<?php echo esc_attr( $country ); ?>"  
      required>
   </div>
```

Where/how would I place the font awesome icon,"fa fa-globe",so it displays on the bottom left of the field. So far I was able to display it below the actual field, by itself, which confuses me further! Also, what is the CSS I would need to apply, (not bothered about colors and sizes right now, I know how to work these out).

Thank you for all the valuable help...

Comment: So I tried this in both variations, however it is proving to be a lot harder than I thought it would be. It messes up with the placement of the rest of the fields and I cannot for the life of me move the icon on the right of the field in the CSS, (as the styling of the rest of the form is). Sorry..I thought I could work this out, I think I'll just leave it for now..!

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer something like this: http://materializecss.com/forms.html
You can get this effect with

```
<div class="input-field col s6"> <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v49pjhfj/

Or you can use:

```
<input placeholder="&#61612; Username"/>
```

with css

```
input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; }
```

If you want to know the placeholder code for other icons: look up the unicode value on [the site](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and [convert it from hex to dec](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter)

http://jsfiddle.net/v49pjhfj/1/

Comment: Hi Thomas..thank you so much for your help. I can't wait to get home and give this a try! Will let you know of the outcome :-)

Comment: @Tony that's cool, but you can already click on the JSFiddle link and test it directly

Comment: So I tried this in both variations, however it is proving to be a lot harder than I thought it would be. It messes up with the placement of the rest of the fields and I cannot for the life of me move the icon on the right of the field in the CSS, (as the styling of the rest of the form is). Sorry..I thought I could work this out, I think I'll just leave it for now..!